# How to get selected value group set in single query for mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, dataset

Here how my tables look like:

CREATE TABLE my_table(id INT,user_id VARCHAR(5));

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES
  (1, 100),
  (2, 200),
  (3, 100),
  (4, 150),
  (5, 200),
  (6, 300),
  (7, 400),
  (8, 500);

what i want

first of all,i need to check the query group by user_id , 
 i got **100,150,200,300,400,500** 
 then check each user_id get sets of its own id value. 
 finally i want this answer
 **user_id** |  **sets** 
 100 | 1,3 
 150 | 4 
 200 | 2,5 
 300 | 6
 400 | 7 
 500 | 8 
note:
 i need single query.
please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function like

```
SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(id separator ",") as sets 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

See using [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a group by, with GROUP_CONCAT to lup the ids together

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS sets
FROM my_table
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_CONCAT function

```
select user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(id) as sets from your_table
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT USER_ID AS USER, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) AS SETS FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY USER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT USER_ID AS USER, GROUP_CONCAT( ID ) AS SETS
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY USER_ID
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This is working with the database you provided